# Highlighting mininimum row value in Pander

Tags: rstudio, pander

I am trying to display a dataframe in an RMarkdown document using the Pander package.

I would like to highlight the minimum value in each row of values. Here's what I have tried:

```
df <- replicate(4, rnorm(5)) 
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$min <- apply(df, 1, min)
emphasize.strong.cells(which(df == df$min, arr.ind = T))
pander(df[1:4])
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
Error in check.highlight.parameters(emphasize.strong.cells, nrow(t), ncol(t)) : 
  Too high number passed for column indexes that should be kept below 6
```

I can print out the whole table (with the min column) without any trouble or I can print out a partial table without emphasis, but neither of these is ideal. I want the highlighting, but I do not wish to include the 'min' column.

I imagine the fact that I am leaving some highlighted cells out of the pander command is causing the error.

Is there a way around this? Or a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Subquestion: What if I wanted to highlight the minimum in the first few rows and the maximum in the next few. Is that possible in a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `which` lookup, with the possibility to match row minimums in the wrong rows, you can easily construct those array indices with a simple sequence (1:N) and calling `which.min` on each row, eg with `apply`:

```
> df <- replicate(4, rnorm(5))
> df <- as.data.frame(df)
> emphasize.strong.cells(cbind(1:nrow(df), apply(df, 1, which.min)))
> pander(df)

----------------------------------------------
    V1          V2          V3          V4    
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
  0.6802      0.1409    **-0.7992**   0.1997  

  0.6797    **-0.2212**    1.016      0.6874  

   2.031     -0.009855    0.3881    **-1.275**

   1.376      0.2619    **-2.337**   -0.1066  

**-0.4541**    1.135      -0.1566     0.2912  
----------------------------------------------
```

About your next question: you could of course do that in a single table, eg `rbind` two matrices created similarly as described above with `which.min` and `which.max`.